# how to do LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE in laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel-5.4, mysql-5.5

i need to convert the following query in laravel 5.4

```
$loadDataToTempTableSql = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '".$filename."' INTO TABLE ABC FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r' IGNORE 1 LINES";
                    $loadDataToTempTableRes = mysqli_query($link,$loadDataToTempTableSql);

                    $loadedData = mysqli_affected_rows($link);
```

what i did

Step1:

```
DB::select($load_data_to_temp_table_sql);
```

which is throwing exception:

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2014 Cannot execute queries while
>   other unbuffered queries are active. Consider using
>   PDOStatement::fetchAll(). Alternatively, if your code is only ever
>   going to run against mysql, you may enable query buffering by setting
>   the PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY attribute. (SQL: LOAD DATA
>   LOCAL INFILE
>   '/Library/WebServer/Documents/public/abc
>   copy.csv' INTO TABLE ABC FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
>   OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '
>       ' IGNORE 1 LINES)

Step2:

```
$pdo = DB::connection()->getPdo();
$pdo->exec($load_data_to_temp_table_sql);
```

again exception:

> PDO::exec(): LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE forbidden

Please guide, what to do?

Answer (score 4):

I have faced same kind of problems and after googling it has been solved now. You should add the following to your `mysql/my.cnf` file:

```
[Server]
local_infile=true
```

After that add `'options'  => array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_LOCAL_INFILE => true)` into your project's `config/database.php` file.

Now restart your MySQL from cmd/terminal. It will be fine to run the `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE`. If you still face a problem, you can visit https://tenerant.com/blog/using-load-data-local-infile-in-a-laravel-migration/.

Answer (score 1):

i didn't work out with DB. i worked out with PDO and then i had to make a addition to  `MYSQL_ATTR_LOCAL_INFILE` to the database.php file in config folder

```
'options' => [PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_LOCAL_INFILE => true],
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is step by step your solution:

Goto/Open config file `config/database.php`

On `connections => mysql` array add following lines to enable local in file.

```
// config/database.php
...
...
'mysql' => [
    ...
    ...
    'driver' => 'mysql',
    'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
        PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
        PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_LOCAL_INFILE => true, // this must be true
    ]) : [],
],
```

Restart server and clear configs and cache:

> `php artisan config:clear`

> `php artisan cache:clear`

> `php artisan serve`

Answer (score 0):

if your using ubuntu or virtual box server with homestead please fullow this:

in your root homestead(with the vagrant file) folder:

vagrant ssh

edit the file:
sudo nano /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld

find:

## Allow data files dir access

and add this line :

/home/Code/NameOfyourProject/public/[name of your upload folder]/* rw

save

then:

sudo service apparmor restart