# Laravel trying to insert data to DB with load data local infile - no errors and no data inserted

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, load-data-infile

```
public function loadDataLocalInfile($table, $columns, $fileName)
    {
        $filePath = Storage::disk('local')->path($fileName);
        $fields = '';
        foreach ($columns as $key => $column) {
            $fields .= $column . ',';
        }
        $fields = rtrim($fields, ',');
        DB::raw("
            LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '" . $filePath . "' 
            INTO TABLE temporary_" . $table . "
            FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';'
            ENCLOSED BY '\"'
            LINES TERMINATED BY '\\n'
            IGNORE 1 LINES (" . $fields . ")");
        $updateColumns = '';
        foreach ($columns as $key => $column) {
            $updateColumns .= $column . ' = VALUES(' . $column . '),';
        }
        $updateColumns = rtrim($updateColumns, ',');
        DB::raw('
            INSERT INTO ' . $table . '
            SELECT * FROM temporary_' . $table . '
            ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ' . $updateColumns);
    }
```

When the script is executed no errors and no data inserted to the DB, all tables exists, when i do

```
print_r(Storage::disk('local')->get($fileName));
```

CSV file is printed

```
"name";"image"
"userNameA";"urlImageA"
"userNameB";"urlImageB"
"userNameC";"urlImageC"
```

I added PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_LOCAL_INFILE => true in options to mysql in config/database.php

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to do LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE in laravel 5.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49633881/how-to-do-load-data-local-infile-in-laravel-5-4)

Comment: If you don't get errors its possible you aren't checking it correctly. The `INSERT INTO` syntax ends with `colname  = VALUES ( colname)` when it corresponds to a duplicate key, In this case the column names have a default value. In this case it will also be a duplicate row also so you are effectively resting to the default values any duplicate row inserted. I'm not sure if this is intentional.

Comment: Main problem is that first query with 'LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE' dont insert data to DB.