# Importing Large CSV file to Mysql Database

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, csv, csv-import

**I have Core php code for importing large csv file into mysql Database and it works fine. i want to use this same technique in laravel and want to convert it into laravel's controller function. below i'm attaching my core php code please help me if anybody can.**

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once('Database.php');
if(isset($_SESSION['admin']) and $_SESSION['admin']!="")
{

if (!empty($_FILES['csvfile']['name']))
{
//$mimes = array('application/vnd.ms-excel','text/plain','text/csv','text/tsv');
$mimes = array(
    'text/csv',
    'text/plain',
    'application/csv',
    'text/comma-separated-values',
    'application/excel',
    'application/vnd.ms-excel',
    'application/vnd.msexcel',
    'text/anytext',
    'application/octet-stream',
    'application/txt',
);
if(in_array($_FILES['csvfile']['type'],$mimes)){
    $file=$_FILES['csvfile']['tmp_name'];
    $fname=basename($file);
 
    //$sql="delete from calls";
    //mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
    $sql="LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/tmp/$fname' 
        INTO TABLE calls
        FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"'
        LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' 
        (`account_code`,`source`,`destination`,`dbcontext`,`caller_id`,`channel`,`destination-channel`,`lastapp`,`lastdata`,`start`,`answer`,`end`,`duration`,`billseconds`,`disposition`,`amaflag`,`call_id`,`userfield`)";
        mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

    header('location:import-csv.php?success=1');
    unlink($file);
} else {
    header('Location:import-csv.php?invalid=1');
}

}
else header('Location:import-csv.php?mandatory=1');
}
else header('Location:index.php');


?>
```

**Here i have tried to convert it into a function but its incomplete.
i actually don't know how to execute/run this query in that function. this function is in Controller.**

```
public function import(Request $request) 
    {
        
        //Excel::import(new CallsImport,request()->file('file'));
        //return redirect()->route('calls.importExportView')->withFlashSuccess(__('Added.'));
        if ($request->hasFile('file')){
            $csv = $request->file('file');
            
            $query="LOAD DATA INFILE '$csv' 
                  INTO TABLE calls
                  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"'
                  LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' 
                  (`account_code`,`source`,`destination`,`dbcontext`,`caller_id`,`channel`,`destination-channel`,`lastapp`,`lastdata`,`start`,`answer`,`end`,`duration`,`billseconds`,`disposition`,`amaflag`,`call_id`,`userfield`)";


                    }

    }
```

Comment: What part of the conversion are you having trouble with?

Comment: i want to make it into a function which is able to run in laravel and do the same as above file code. 
function recieve a file in $request variable and then further did the same as above.

Comment: There are loads of tutorials out there that show how to import CSV using Laravel. Check this one out - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35220048/import-csv-file-to-laravel-controller-and-insert-data-to-two-tables. There are also full-blown packages that do all the heavy lifting for you. If your file is very big, look into _chunking_. But that is a big enough topic for a whole new question.

Comment: Are you asking how to use Laravel? I mean, have you got routes set up and able to access this controller/action? Or is that where you're stuck?

Comment: yes this function is accessible through post route which take file from form input and take that file into this function. My issue is to run the above mentioned php query "LOCAL DATA INFILE........" in that function. so that it works well in laravel. All other libraries and queries i have tried they work well but very slow. my CSV file has 4 lac+ records.

Comment: Right now i want to convert the above code in laravel function as i mentioned above.Can you be able to write it into a function ?

Comment: Take a look here - https://stackoverflow.com/q/49633881/296555.